# Replacing all proceeding underscores with 1 underscore using a regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need some help, I have a string which looks like below:

```
$p__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________, &$s___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________, &$k____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________, &$nft_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________)
```

and was wondering if I could use a regex to turn it into:

```
$p_, &$s_, &$k_, &$nft_)
```

Which is basically removing all the (so theirs no specific amount but theirs atleast 1) proceeding underscores, and replace them with 1 underscore.

I've tried the following pattern but no luck:

```
preg_replace('#(\$[a-z]{1,3})[_]+#', '$1', $string);
```

PS: The reason a preg_replace (regex) is preffered (although I understand its not 100% always correct) because it's more precise then using a regular string replacing function.

Thanks and appreciate all help.

Comment: Do you realy want to do that in regex? I think it is easier and faster when combining some basic php functions (explode(), while() or string manipulation function)

Comment: So many people worried about regex performance, so few benchmarks :) Truthfully, unless you're doing this millions of times in one go, you're unlikely to ever notice a performance impact from using regex functions, and one `preg_replace()` is much easier to write and explain than some combination of other string manipulators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $string);
```

thought for something so simple, you'd get better performance from [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: Note that `str_replace` will only work well if you know the exact length of each underscore sequence.

Comment: I'd tweak the regex to this: `preg_replace('/__+/', '_', $string);`. This minor edit will prevent useless replacements on single underscores.

Answer (score 0):

you can try replacing _ with space using 'str_replace'and then trim spaces them at right side! and then add a _ at the end of string. I dont know a direct way sorry! imo this is faster than regex

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, just forgot a `_` after the variable.

If you need an anchor -

\$letters anchor: `#(\$[a-z]{1,3}_)_+#` with `$1`

Letter anchor: `#([a-z]_)_+#` with `$1`

Any anchor: `#((?:^|[^_])_)_+#` with `$1`